# Report Columns not in the right order

Tags: civireport

I would like to reorder report columns.  Is there a way to do this?  It looks like someone else has asked a similar question ([Reorder Report Column](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17525/reorder-report-columns)) but it looks like the answer is to use some other program to make this happen.  I'm wanting to use this report as a dashlette so using a different program won't work for me.  I'm willing to look into custom coding if it is needed.  I'm using 5.16.4  Thanks.

Comment: I would just add a comment at that question asking if there's any update since 2017, since this seems like a duplicate question. You can also ask at chat.civicrm.org.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the other question - but there's a much better answer these days!  I just added the answer to the other question, so check it out :)

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the answers.  I'll check out the new extension.